# problem in reading form dataframe and series in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda series like this

```
75020                                                5-9-34
75021                                                    12
75022                                                    33
```

I converted to dataframe then I try to write this to know where 33 is found
s6 = df.stack().isin(['33'])

here, the result is true, and it write true behind 75022
but if I write
s6 = df.stack().isin(['34'])
it write false behind all

So, it know if no number with it
why? what's the problem? and how can I solve problem?

Comment: it is `5-9-34` instead of `34`?

Comment: Yes it's work , but I don't want together , I want each number alone

Comment: like 5,9,34 should be same for 75020?

Comment: yes it run true. but I need to separate numbers. how can I separate it  then run true ?

Comment: what are your column names?

Comment: 'level_1' is the name

Comment: and another column name?

Comment: the other is index.. So, the first one is index (for example: 75020 ), the other is 'level_1' for example (5-9-34)